# search bar I can't find anything

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar

I'm new to coding and I've been trying to code the search bar for a while now but I've found that my search bar has a problem where it doesn't search what I want, it seems like it can't find anything. I tried to fix it for a while but still got the same problem. I studied from different websites. and then fix it, still stuck on the same problem, I think maybe I wrote the code in a wrong place but my code doesn't have any error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGrS.png)

```
class view_problem extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  State<view_problem> createState() => _view_problemState();
}

class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      getAllProblem();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _filterSearch(String query) {
    List<problemModel> filteredList = [];
    for (var item in problemlist) {
      if (item.toString().contains(query.toString())) {
        filteredList.add(item);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      problemlist = filteredList;
    });
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
        title: const Text('show information'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _filterSearch(value);
                },
                controller: _searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                           problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.area,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                 problem.status,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
       ),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `itemCount: problemlist.length` have to be `itemCound: snapshots.data.length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a timer running periodically running every second forever that gets all problems, which will overwrite any filtering. I don't think you want that timer there, and just do getAllProblem(); once in the initState. And save the originalList in another variable. Something like this

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  List<problemModel> originalList = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    originalList = problemlist;
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAllProblem();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _filterSearch(String query) {
    List<problemModel> filteredList = [];
    for (var item in originalList) {
      if (item.toString().contains(query.toString())) {
        filteredList.add(item);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      problemlist = filteredList;
    });
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
        title: const Text('show information'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _filterSearch(value);
                },
                controller: _searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                           problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.area,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                 problem.status,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
       ),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello I followed your suggestion, it looks better than my old code. But the results from the search still do not show the result I've searched for information but it doesn't show what I'm looking for.No results are showing.